# ASP Classic SQL Multiple parameters

Tags: sql, asp-classic

What is the ASP Classic SQL query equivalent for this Oracle SQL:

```
SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE column2 = '&num' AND column2 LIKE '&nam%';
```

Comment: That question doesn't make sense. Oracle SQL can be run from a classic ASP page.

Comment: There is an equivalent for the above code...

Comment: For example: SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE column2 = '&num'

Comment: is equivalent to ASP Classic SQL query: mQry = "SELECT column1 Where column2 = " & request.querystring("&num")  ---- this for a single parameter only

Comment: What if I got two or more parameters as stated in my question..?

Comment: What would that ASP Classic SQL Query might be...???

Comment: Research ADODB Objects (Recordset, Command, Connection). Query is SQL language, it would be the same, you need to learn how to call it, how to assign parameters etc.

Answer (score 1):

read about classic asp, adodb and so on, really!

here's a untested example:

```
sql = "SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE column2 = ? AND column3 LIKE ? + '%'"

set cmd = server.createobject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.activeconnection = yourConnection
cmd.commandText = SQL

cmd.Parameters.Append( cmd.CreateParameter("column2", adVarchar, , 512, valOfColumn2) )
cmd.Parameters.Append( cmd.CreateParameter("column3", adVarchar, , 512, valOfColumn3) )

set rs = cmd.execute
```

Note that the syntax for string concetenation in the SQL string could differ per database System. i don't know the Syntax in Oracle... by that i mean the "LIKE ? + '%'" Portion of the SQL string.

Furthermore i do not know the definition of your table so i assumed column2 and column3 are varchar fields with a length of 512.

Finally [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms807498.aspx) is a link to MSDN for your further reading about ADODB.Command and so on.

And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.90%29.aspx/css) is a link about SQL-Injection - READ IT!.